# Get application icon from ProcessSerialNumber

Tags: c++, cocoa, macos, macos-carbon

I would like to get the application icon for all foreground applications running on my Mac. I'm already iterating over all applications using the [Process Manager](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Process_Manager/Reference/reference.html) API. I have determined that any process that does not have the `modeBackgroundOnly` flag set in the `processMode` (as retrieved from `GetProcessInformation()`) is a "foreground" application, and shows up in the task switcher window.

All I need is an API that gives me a CImageRef (or similar) that contains the application icon for a process. I'm free to use either carbon or cocoa APIs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Mac OS X 10.6 or later, you can [ask a running application for its icon](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSRunningApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSRunningApplication/icon).

On earlier versions of Mac OS X, you'll have to get it by looking at the application's bundle. Pass the PSN to [the `GetProcessBundleLocation` function](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Process_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/GetProcessBundleLocation) to get the bundle's location as an `FSRef`, then pass that to [the `GetIconRefFromFileInfo` function](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/IconServices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/GetIconRefFromFileInfo).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [LaunchServices](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference/Reference/reference.html) functions (Carbon) or the [NSWorkspace](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class (Cocoa).