# Qt: c++/carbon OSX - Getting Application Icon from Process ID

Tags: macos, qt, macos-carbon

On my C++ application, I am using carbon for some mac platform specific work.

I have: Mac Process ID for a running application.

I need: a Qt image object (can be pixmap, QImage, QIcon) for the running application belonging to that Process ID.

Any pointers?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453318/get-application-icon-from-processserialnumber

Qt QPixmap has method fromCGImageRef

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`GetProcessForPID()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Process_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/GetProcessForPID) will get you the `ProcessSerialNumber` of the `pid`. [`ProcessInformationCopyDictionary()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Process_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/ProcessInformationCopyDictionary) will then get you a `CFDictionary` containing the path to the application bundle.

Use [`QFileIconProvider`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qfileiconprovider.html#icon-2) to get the icon from the path.